# Lisp disabling ASDF warning

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp, asdf

I wrote my first SBCl Lisp program, which will be execute from the command line. I use the following command for execution:

```
sbcl --noinform --noprint --load processfile.fasl --eval '(progn (parse_graph "infile.txt" 3 4) (sb-ext:quit))'
```

And it works fine with one exception. I use

```
(ql:quickload "split-sequence")
```

For sequence splitting, and the program outputs:

```
To load "split-sequence":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    split-sequence
; Loading "split-sequence"
```

at the beginning of each run. How does one disable this annoying text?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `(ql:quickload "..." :silent t)` should work. You might consider saving a core instead, so that you don't need to load it every time (the startup time would be a lot faster).

Comment: Thanks, this worked! A core? As in an own function for this?

Comment: You can load everything and then save the lisp image into a file. Then you can restore it with `sbcl --core corefile args...`. See [SBCL Manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Saving-a-Core-Image).

Comment: Or use cl-launch and be portable.

Comment: Currently I use Buildapp to obtain binary executable, which works OK for linux machines I am dealing with!